# Button rendered differently in Firefox vs Webkit

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a couple of buttons inside a div with a specific width, and I am facing a problem where the buttons are being rendered differently in firefox vs chrome and safari.

In firefox, the buttons are bigger and are messing up my layout.

```
<div id="sort_by">
    <button id="sort_by_price" class="sortButton" value="1">Price</button>
    <button id="sort_by_bedrooms" class="sortButton" value="1">Bedrooms</button>
    <button id="compareButton" class="sortButton">Compare</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
display:inline;
float:left;
background-color:orange;
border:1px solid orange;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;

font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
padding:4px 10px 3px 7px;

}

#sort_by {
width:265px;
height:35px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:2px;
border-color:#c9c9c9;
padding-top:3px;
padding-bottom:3px;
padding-left:5px;
}
```

Rendered in firefox:

[image]

Rendered in Chrome:

[image]

It can be seen that the buttons in firefox are bigger. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firefox adds an extra margin/padding to `button` elements that cannot be changed by standard CSS, you can however add the following to make it behave

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I already reseted using YUI reset. I looked into the code and they don't seem to have included the button element. Weird.

Comment: @alexBrand I updated my answer with some additional info, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By playing around with that CSS rule I was able to get almost the exact same rendering.